# Display xml in pop-up window

Tags: xml, popup, show, jscript

I want to display some XML text in a pop-up browser window in Chrome. This is all client-side. I use window.open to create the pop-up, then window.document.open & window.document.write to write my xml string. I want to see the XML tags as well as the XML node values. I also want to be able to right-click & save-as to save the original XML document. My code so far is:

```
var w = window.open(null, null, config='height=400,width=400, addressbar=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=vertical, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no');
w.document.open("text/plain", "replace");
w.document.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>' + xmlStr);
w.document.close();
```

All I get in the new window is the node text values, and the "save-as" option is disabled. Has anyone got any ideas?